# When should I use fb:admins and fb:appid?

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

I have a client who already has a Facebook page associated with their own website. I finally convinced them to integrate open graph tags into their pages, since when anyone clicked the Facebook Like button on their website, it looked awful on Facebook (since it chose whatever images and content it wanted).

I have admin access to their Facebook page, however, they are using the fb:appid tag instead of fb:admins on their website, so I can't see any of the insights on Facebook.

So I need to be made an admin of their Facebook application as well, in order to see the insights?

I've read dozens of forums and posts about this, including Facebook's own Open Graph documentation and I still don't REALLY understand the difference between fb:admins and fb:appid. As far as I can tell, fb:appid is more for developer/programming access, whereas fb:admins is for those who just want reports and insights for page activity.

In what circumstances would I want to use fb:appid over fb:admins?

EDIT : Let me clarify. I can already view insights for the company's Facebook page. What I want to do, is see the insights for users who have clicked the Like button on the website.

Answer (score 15):

fb:app_id is the most flexible one to use.

It allows anyone who's listed in the app settings as an admin, developer or insights user to see their domain or app insights. This means as people join or leave a company, they update their app in one place, and access to things like insights changes too.

fb:admins is for User IDs, and once they've been associated with a URL or domain, they remain connected with that domain until their removed from the root HTML document.

fb:page_id works in the same way as fb:app_id in that access to insights is controlled by the list of people who are admins of that page.

As app_ids are becoming more and more important as you integrate with the deeper bits of the Facebook platform (use connect, comments etc) I STRONGLY suggest you use fb:app_id, claim your domain using this, and manage access to insights via your app's settings.

Comment: Thanks for the useful info. I've now been added as an admin to their Facebook App, however the insights are all listing 0. They have been using the App_id for weeks and have had thousands of likes on their website content so I know this isn't accurate.  Am I missing something? <meta property='fb:app_id' content='1234567890' /> is on every page on their site (obviously a fake number).

Comment: Is this in application insights, or insights for websites. They are two different products. adding fb:app_id doesn't make website stats show up in app insights, it just gives developers of the app access to the insights for website dashboard.